# Amazon Instant video not working because HDCP

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer-9, amazon-web-services, hdcp

I am trying to watch a show on my laptop with Amazon Instant video but it is telling my that my PC does not support HDCP.  I'm running windows at 1920x1080 just fine.

My laptop has a GTX 470m and a very high quality display.  I have tried running Amazon Instant video in both Chrome and IE9 but neither of them work.  Is there any way that I can get this to work on my laptop?

P.S. this works just find on my work laptop which is a very small POS computer and that's why I'm so confused that I am getting an error when I try to run it on my very nice personal computer.

[image]

Comment: Have you followed the troubleshooting tips?

Comment: I have, but they are not even tips, really - just information about streaming.

Comment: Just because your running at 1920x1080 does not mean your laptop has ability to make a HDCP connection.  Are you using HDMI, DVI, VGA to connect to your monitor?

Comment: I'm using my built in monitor.

Comment: @Ramhound To date, I have never seen a "troubleshooting tip" on a company website that is actually useful.

Comment: @Navin - I personally have.  The reason I asked is because the troubleshooting tips had the author's solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some research and found out that it was a silverlight problem.  By disabling silverlight I was able to get my Amazon Instant video working.  I'm not sure exactly why that is, but it worked.

Comment: Same here, but the flash player on my computer it jittery :(